# Android Studio incorrect package name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, package

I recently changed the package name of my Android application in the Eclipse IDE. Then, I imported it into Android Studio. However, I noticed when running the app that it said

```
Target device: AVD_for_10_1_WXGA_Tablet [emulator-5556]
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\AppName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.oldpackage.appname
Installing com.oldpackage.appname
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.oldpackage.appname"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.oldpackage.appname
Success.
```

It is still using the old package name!

I have tried many fixes I found on StackOverflow, including restarting, deleting `/.gradle/taskartifacts`(cache), and syncing project with gradle files. Does anyone know how to get my package name completely updated?

Comment: Please post the build.gradle of your app module.

Comment: Edited to add build.gradle

Comment: There's a second build.gradle file in another directory - that's the high level one which doesn't have the information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was looking at the wrong build.gradle file and didn't see the application id value. Once I found the correct file (thanks to @ianhanniballake) I changed the application id and it worked.